# Is there a way to resolve this error in R, data frame warning

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create a data frame for my analysis but I'm getting two errors and despite all the research or edits, I have tried it's not working.
when I ran this code im getting warnings

```
Treasury = data.frame(Treasury2$DGS_2,Treasury3$DGS_3,Treasury5$DGS_5,
+  Treasury7$DGS_7,Treasury10$DGS_10,Treasury30$DGS_30)
> colnames(Treasury) = c("Date","DGS_2","DGS_3","DGS_5","DGS_7","DGS_10","DGS_30")
Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [7] must be the same length as the vector [6]
>
```

this is my code up to this level

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)
library(matrixStats)
library(YieldCurve)
library(tseries)

Treasury2 = read_excel("DGS_2.xlsx", col_names = TRUE)
Treasury3 = read_excel("DGS_3.xlsx", col_names = TRUE)
Treasury5 = read_excel("DGS_5.xlsx", col_names = TRUE)
Treasury7 = read_excel("DGS_7.xlsx", col_names = TRUE)
Treasury10 = read_excel("DGS_10.xlsx", col_names = TRUE)
Treasury30 = read_excel("DGS_30.xlsx", col_names = TRUE)


GLD = read.csv("GLD.csv", header = TRUE)
IEFA = read.csv("IEFA.csv", header = TRUE)

gld = Return.calculate(xts(GLD$Adj.Close, order.by = as.Date(GLD$Date)), method = c("log"))
iefa = Return.calculate(xts(IEFA$Adj.Close, order.by = as.Date(IEFA$Date)), method = c("log"))
Treasury = data.frame(Treasury2$DGS_2,Treasury3$DGS_3,Treasury5$DGS_5, Treasury7$DGS_7,Treasury10$DGS_10,Treasury30$DGS_30)
colnames(Treasury) = c("Date","DGS_2","DGS_3","DGS_5","DGS_7","DGS_10","DGS_30")
```

what mistakes am I making when creating a data frame?
thanks for the support in advance.

Comment: Looks like an issue with your data import. Check head(treasury2) and str(treasury2).

Comment: @Roland i'm getting this error now Error in head(treasury2) : object 'treasury2' not found

Comment: Sorry, you need to capitalize Treasury2.

Comment: @Roland thanks for it has given me a clue and i checked my data some columns were not properly market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message suggests that you are passing column names of length 7 whereas your dataframe has only 6 columns. I think you don't have `Date` column in your dataframe.

Try with -

```
colnames(Treasury) = c("DGS_2","DGS_3","DGS_5","DGS_7","DGS_10","DGS_30")
```

Alternatively you can assign the column name while creating the dataframe.

```
Treasury = data.frame(DGS_2 = Treasury2$DGS_2,
                      DGS_3 = Treasury3$DGS_3,
                      DGS_5 = Treasury5$DGS_5,
                      DGS_7 = Treasury7$DGS_7,
                      DGS_10 = Treasury10$DGS_10,
                      DGS_30 = Treasury30$DGS_30)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `setNames`

```
setNames(Treasury,  c("DGS_2","DGS_3","DGS_5","DGS_7","DGS_10","DGS_30"))
```